# Jquery getJSON - Get items

Tags: jquery

how can i get the auhtor name from this getJSON

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tPYtsDPXtOY/comments?alt=json-in-script&callback=jsonp1282584741426&max-results=10

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/tPYtsDPXtOY/comments?alt=json-in-script&callback=jsonp1282584741426&max-results=10', function(data) {

 $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {                
    var title = item['content']['$t']; // work
    var author = item['author']['$t']; // dont work         
    $('body').append('['+author+'] <br /> '+title+'<hr/>');
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the response JSON, it seems you can change

```
var author = item['author']['$t']; // dont work
```

to

```
var author = item['author'][0]['name']['$t'];
```

I'm not sure if you can have more than one author though.

Comment: Just a note: this would have been a great use of Firebug. You could have written console.log(item) in the loop to get a breakdown of the properties on each item. Then you could have drilled down and found the answer.

http://getfirebug.com/ in case you're not using it.